# IIS Windows Auth - HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is Null

Tags: .net, iis, subdomain, windows-authentication

I have an asp.net web app I am hosting on Windows 2016 Server using IIS. It is using Windows authentication and working been working successfully for me when testing. One of my colleagues in a different domain is reporting issues accessing the system, and after further investigation, all the other people we've tried in the second domain get a null reference exception when the code tries to get their userID using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name value.

Our Domain structure is pretty simple, we have our "company.com" level which has two children, "UK.company.com" and "US.company.com".

My web app server is hosted on a server in our UK.company.com domain, as am I, and I have never experienced this issue before in the years past where users from the US domain have been able to use my apps without issue.

Can anyone offer any suggestions of things to try?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like anonymous authentication is still enabled, and thus allowing a user access without authenticating.

Make sure your web.config has:

```
<anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
```